# valueChangeListener never called

Tags: java, jsf, valuechangelistener

I have the following bits of code:

```
 <h:panelGroup rendered="#{userTypeController.permissionItemsUserType.contains(item)}">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox valueChangeListener="#{userTypeController.permissionChanged(this)}" value="#{true}"/> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.getAction()}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!userTypeController.permissionItemsUserType.contains(item)}">
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{false}"/> 
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.getAction()}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
```

But for some reason the permissionChanged method is never called. Any ideas of what might be going wrong?

My permissionChanged method:

```
    public void PermissionChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("test");
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. Your listener method call in EL is wrong. You should not pass the current component along it.

   Replace

   ```
   valueChangeListener="#{userTypeController.permissionChanged(this)}"
   ```

   by

   ```
   valueChangeListener="#{userTypeController.permissionChanged}"
   ```
2. Your method signature in backing bean is wrong. It should conform the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

   Replace

   ```
   public void PermissionChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
   ```

   by

   ```
   public void permissionChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
   ```
3. You seem to be expecting that it fires immediately when you click the checkbox (otherwise you'd have seen an `ELException`). This expectation is not true. It will only be fired when you submit the form. Using `onclick="submit()"` is a common hack/workaround for this.

That said, there are likely better ways for this. As the functional requirement is unclear, it is not possible to propose the right solution. I think that the `<f:ajax>` is what you're looking for if all you want is immediate and asynchronous feedback and re-render. Although the JSF 2.0 tag is missing from your question, based on your question history you're using JSF 2.0, so `<f:ajax>` should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSF 1.2 cannot pass an argument to listener. You use:

```
"#{userTypeController.permissionChanged}"
```

Read [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/JSF_chap8/index1.html?page=2).

Comment: Passing method arguments is not specific to JSF, but to EL. If the OP were not using EL 2.2 or JBoss EL, it would surely have thrown an `ELException`.